# How hot should things be getting when I measure them with an ammeter?

Tags: current-measurement

I recently got a little LED voltage and current meter and I've been playing around with it. When I hold down both of the current measuring leads to the battery, the negative terminal heat up significantly - to hot to touch! Since I've been testing lithium based batteries my guess is that the heat is due to the high current, or due to me messing something up, maybe even making a short circuit. Does anyone have any insight into why this could be?

Comment: You are short circuiting the battery.  This is not a good idea, especially with lithium cells.

Comment: At least you didn't try to measure the short circuit current of the AC coming into your house (that would be equivalent to a samsung galaxy 7 level experiment).

Comment: You should probably read how to use a multimeter before you go around probing whatever is in your house https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-multimeter

Answer (score 6):

If you're using an ammeter across a battery then you are essentially shorting it and it will get very hot, and possibly cause damage. Don't do this!

Answer (score 3):

A meter in current mode looks like a short circuit. So connecting it across a battery with no other components will be bad for battery and meter.

Try connecting it in series with a load such as a lightbulb / LED.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to test capacity of a battery without internal sensor(s) is to charge and drain it and observe how long you can extract a given current out of it.

More sophisticated battery chargers do this for you.

As others pointed out, shorting battery is double minus ungood. Even when used in a reasonable way a multimeter will get hot in current measurement mode. So you shouldn't leave it alone for a long time if you're measuring significant current. "Significant" depends on the meter but whatever the meter is rated for (10A etc) will most likely overheat it over time.